Is the category $\mathbf{Set}$ isomorphic to the category $\mathbf{Set} \times \mathbf{Set}$?
I'm starting to take a course in Category Theory and we've just started learning about the product category and a question sprung into my mind.
I've already seen that the category $\mathbf{Set}$ is not isomorphic to its dual, but is it isomorphic to $\mathbf{Set} \times \mathbf{Set}$? My intuition tells me this is not the case, and I believe there would be a problem with pairs of sets that involve the empty set, but I'm stuck trying to formalize this. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Amused by the voter who voted to close this as "opinion-based"!

Your intuition is correct; here's a hint for how to exploit it. Remember that in the product category, a morphism is a pair of morphisms from the "factor" categories acting separately on the components. So consider for instance the $Set\times Set$-objects $$x=(\emptyset, a)\quad\mbox{and}\quad y=(a,\emptyset)$$ with $a$ some fixed nonempty set. Are there, in $Set\times Set$, any morphisms from $x$ to $y$? Are there any morphisms from $y$ to $x$? And, do you see why the answers to these questions show that $Set\times Set\not\cong Set$?

In $\mathbf{Set}$, the monoid $\mathrm{End}(1+1)$ has $4$ elements, where $1$ denotes the terminal object and $+$ is the coproduct. In $\mathbf{Set}^2$, however, the monoid $\mathrm{End}(1+1)$ has $16$ elements. Thus, $\mathbf{Set}$ is not equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}^2$.

Given two sets $S,T$ there always exists a map $S\to T$ or a map $T\to S.$
If $S$ is a non-empty set, then there is no map between $(\emptyset,S)$ and $(S,\emptyset)$ in either direction in $\mathcal{Set}\times\mathcal{Set}.$

This even shows that $\mathbf{Set}$ is not equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}^2$. Even that there is no fully faithful functor $\mathbf{Set}^2 \to \mathbf{Set}$. The same holds for $\mathbf{Set}^I$ for any set $I$ unless it has exactly one element.

Both $\mathsf{Set}$ and $\mathsf{Set}^2$ have what is called a subobject classifier: this is, roughly speaking, an object $\Omega$ such that for each object $X$ there is a natural bijection between the subobjects of $X$ on the one hand, and $\operatorname{Hom}(X, \Omega)$ on the other hand.  (The subobjects of $X$, in turn, are defined as equivalence classes of the monomorphisms with $X$ as a target under a certain natural equivalence relation.)
In $\mathsf{Set}$, the subobject classifier is $\Omega_{\mathsf{Set}} = \{ 0, 1 \}$, so if $1 = \{ * \}$ is a terminal object of $\mathsf{Set}$, then $\operatorname{Hom}(1, \Omega_{\mathsf{Set}})$ has two elements.  On the other hand, in $\mathsf{Set}^2$, the subobject classifier is $\Omega_{\mathsf{Set}^2} = \{ 0, 1 \}^2$, so $\operatorname{Hom}(1, \Omega_{\mathsf{Set}^2})$ has four elements.
(Yes, this is somewhat more complex than some of the other solutions.  However, it is likely to be the first proof a topos theoretician will come up with.)

Just to add another answer in the big list spirit: there are two different functors $\mathbf{Set}\times \mathbf{Set}\to \mathbf{Set}$ which preserve the terminal object and all coproducts: the projections $(A,B)\mapsto A$ and $(A,B)\mapsto B.$ Since every set is a coproduct of copies of the terminal object, it's easy to see that there is only one such functor $\mathbf{Set}\to \mathbf{Set}.$ Since isomorphisms of categories respect preservation of coproducts and terminal objects, this resolves the question (and with a tad more work shows that these categories aren't equivalent either.)

Well, much easier then: in the category of sets, every object is a coproduct of copies of the terminal object. And this is clearly not the case for the product category.

@MartinBrandenburg Right, thanks!
